# Jest: Object value within toMatchObject method is array and check have length (not empty)

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, jestjs

I writing Jest tests with `.toMatchObject()` and have the following problem. Some of my object's values are arrays, and I want to test do they have length or empty.

My code right now:

```
test('suite one', async () => {
  //return { key_one: ["string", ...], key_two: .... }
  const result = await function(args);
  expect(result).toMatchObject({
    key_one: expect.any(Array),
    key_two: expect.any(OtherResult),
    ...
  })
})
```

I understand, that I always have an option to extend `expect` but is there any other option to achieve desired results within `toMatchObject` stage, and without of writing additional string after `toMatchObject` with `expect(result.key_one).toHaveLength(1)`?

Comment: No, there are no other options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as [@Estus Flask mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66760118/jest-object-value-within-tomatchobject-method-is-array-and-check-have-length-n/67018878#comment118013265_66760118), there is now such option nowdays.

*But if Jest will add this feature somehow, to write your own answer and tag me to update an `answered mark` for you.*